# Evaluation of stanford crf classifier

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am doing NER classifier for three tags (PER, ORG, LOC). I am checking my results based on stanford crf classifier. Therefore I would like to know how does the stanford crf classifier evaluation part works. Does it take into account all of the TAGS (PER, ORG, LOC, O) or only (PER, ORG, LOC)??

Answer (score 1):

The score is F1 based on recall and precision of extracted entities.  If you have a tagging scheme such as (PER, ORG, LOC), an entity is simply a sequence of consecutive tokens with the same tag.  Note that sequences of tokens with the `O` label are not considered entities.

The final report gives F1 for all entities, and also gives F1 scores for each entity type.

Note also, there is no partial credit.  You either find an entity correctly or do not.  So in the example sentence "Joe Smith lives in California.", both "Joe" and "Smith" have to be tagged as `PERSON` to get a correctly found `PERSON` entity.  If just "Joe" was tagged as `PERSON` (and "Smith" was tagged as `O`), you would get a score of 0 correct `PERSON` entities and 1 incorrect `PERSON` entity.